# Calculate the distance between two points for every item in DF multiple times

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, for-loop, geospatial

Lets say we have 2 DataFrames:

DF1

```
     name  latitude   longitude
0    A     40.730610  -73.935242
1    B     42.095554  -79.238609
2    C     31.442778  -100.450279
```

DF2

```
     name  latitude   longitude
0    AA     40.560001  -74.290001
1    BB     33.193611  -117.241112
2    CC     41.676388  -86.250275
3    DD     34.155834  -119.202789
```

With

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic, great_circle
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
print(geodesic(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
```

one can calculate the distance between two points.
How can I calculate the distances for A, B, C in DF1 to every item in DF2 (AA, BB, CC, DD) and safe these information in a different DF or dictionary?

Should approx look like this:

```
   from   to   distance
   A      AA   5
   A      BB   2
   ...
   C      DD   16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first build a cartesian product of both dataframes:

```
resul = df1.set_index(np.zeros(len(df1), 'int')).join(df2.set_index(np.zeros(len(df2), 'int')),
                                                lsuffix='_1', rsuffix='_2').reset_index(drop=True)
```

to get:

```
   name_1  latitude_1  longitude_1 name_2  latitude_2  longitude_2
0       A   40.730610   -73.935242     AA   40.560001   -74.290001
1       A   40.730610   -73.935242     BB   33.193611  -117.241112
2       A   40.730610   -73.935242     CC   41.676388   -86.250275
3       A   40.730610   -73.935242     DD   34.155834  -119.202789
4       B   42.095554   -79.238609     AA   40.560001   -74.290001
5       B   42.095554   -79.238609     BB   33.193611  -117.241112
6       B   42.095554   -79.238609     CC   41.676388   -86.250275
7       B   42.095554   -79.238609     DD   34.155834  -119.202789
8       C   31.442778  -100.450279     AA   40.560001   -74.290001
9       C   31.442778  -100.450279     BB   33.193611  -117.241112
10      C   31.442778  -100.450279     CC   41.676388   -86.250275
11      C   31.442778  -100.450279     DD   34.155834  -119.202789
```

It is now easy to compute the distances:

```
df[distance] = df.apply(lambda x: geodesic((x['latitude_1'], x['longitude_1']),
                                           (x['latitude_2'], x['longitude_2'])), axis=1)
```

You can now drop unneeded columns and/or rename them...